# Cannot display picture php

Tags: php

This is my .php file

```
<?php
        ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br/>
                <input type="file" name="image" />
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
                {
                    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
                    {
                        echo "Please select an image.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

                        $image= file_get_contents($image);
                        $image= base64_encode($image);
                        saveimage($image);
                    }
                }
                displayimage();
                function saveimage($image)
                {
                    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("food",$con);
                    $qry="insert into info (image) values ('$image')";
                    $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                    if($result)
                    {
                        echo "<br/>Image uploaded.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<br/>Image not uploaded.";
                    }
                }

                function displayimage()
                {
                    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("food",$con);
                    $qry="select image from info";
                    $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
                    }
                    mysql_close($con);   
                }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Why i cannot display my picture when i add it. The picture is stored in the database already when i click upload but i cant display it. Is there anything wrong with the display code there?Thanks

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead. Also check for Errors after executing an SQL query

Comment: First of all. stop using `mysql_*`, those functions are depecated and really unsafe. 2nd: what happens, when you dump `$row` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ...
```

You're fetching the row as an associative array, not as a numeric array, so `$row[2]` won't work. Use `$row['image']` in your `<img>` element to display the image.

So your code should be like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'. $row['image'] . '">';
}
```

---

**Sidenotes:**

1. Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).
2. Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your queries are susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

In your current code change here

Replace `$row[2]` to `$row['image']`

And Try to convert your code as commented suggestion.

Comment: it stil cannot works..it display sumthing like whole page alien words

Comment: show what error you are getting ?

Comment: its okay. I fix it alreadyi forgot putting a single quotes thanks